# runtests option to run a single test from file

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

Is there a way to run a single test in a `matlab.unittest.TestCase` class? I have a file with about 15 tests but I only want to run one of them. I normally run the whole file with

```
runtests('test/disaggregationtests.m')
```

I was expecting to be able to do something like

```
runtests('test/disaggregationtests.m', 'Name', 'testWeekDisaggGrowth')
```

but this results in an empty `TestResult`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of this depends on the version of MATLAB you are using, but there are a variety of ways to run a single test, as well as multiple ways to determine what a single test is, since with test parameterization ([[1]](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-basic-parameterized-test.html), [[2]](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-advanced-parameterized-test.html), [[3]](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/use-external-parameters-in-parameterized-test.html)) a single test method can actually produce multiple tests that can each independently run. Note the "Name" of each test matches the name property of the Test array returned by `testsuite`  or `TestSuite.fromFile`, etc. It is also what shows when a failure happens.

Here are a couple things you can do in the most recent version of MATLAB (R2019a). Earlier versions may have differing support.

1) Run through directly using the name as the first argument (test must be available on the path, hence the cd)

```
>> cd test
>> runtests disaggregationtests/testWeekDisaggGrowth
```

2) Use the Name of the test as a name/value pair. EDIT: you can simply point to the folder as the first arg

```
>> runtests('test', 'Name', 'disaggregationtests/testWeekDisaggGrowth')
```

3) Use the [run tests toolstrip button](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-tests-in-editor.html) to run the test where your current cursor is in the editor. Note this will run all parameterizations of chosen test so it may or may not be what you want.

[image: Run Current Test]

4) Use the TestProcedure name value pair. Note this will run all parameterizations of chosen test so it may or may not be what you want

```
>> runtests('test/disaggregationtests.m', 'TestProcedure', 'testWeekDisaggGrowth')
```

Hope that helps!